# A server like DynDNS?

Tags: dns

[www.dyndns.com] is a site which gives us internet service,

If I use their service and get a domain name with an i.p.

Their server will transfer the domain name to 1.2.3.4 when someone browse it.

what did they do at the back? how can they do this?

can I set up a server like that?

Comment: Please make you question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this link you will find you answer there.

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/dns2.htm

If you make you question clearer I could provide a better answer.

If you wish to create a local DNS on your system I would suggest you make alterations to your hosts file. Located at `C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc` in windows system.

The order in which DNS names are resolved is:

1. HOSTS configuration file
2. The DNS to which your computer is confugured

The HOSTS file has the highest priority so you could override the DNS server by configuring an IP in your HOSTS file.